# Custom Attribute to filter properties with null value

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I am trying to decorate my field with an attribute which will make the model `ModelState.IsValid` to `false` if the string field is either null or empty.

I created a class and inherited the `System.Attribute`.
I am not able to move ahead, like accessing the value, triggering the method to check and returning the response.

Please note, I tried the `Required` attribute under `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` but it is not blocking `null` values.

I am learning the ropes, so please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accessing the field via binding?

If yes, may be  a converter could be your solution.
Uer a converter which converts from string to bool
see
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/